# Is there a way we can query two tables from two different databases in Google Spanner?

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-platform, rdbms, google-cloud-spanner

I want to query two different tables from two different databases in Google Spanner. I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT T1.C1
      ,T2.C3
      ,T2.C4
FROM Database1.Table1 T1 
INNER JOIN Database2.Table2 T2
ON T1.C1 = T2.C2
```

However, when I use database name along with the table name (Database.table), I receive an error

> Table not found: 'Database.table'

Is there any other way I can achieve this or the only workaround for this is to create all the tables in the same database?

Answer (score 4):

No, as you have found, there is no way of joining tables in two separate databases - the spanner client is per-database.

Either have all tables in one database, or perform the join at the application level, using a spanner client instance per database instance.